# Macro Select all for Pivot tables

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am trying to make a macro for creating a pivot table. I need the Macro to select all of the data on the sheet; a friend of mine has helped me create the code above, however the macro only selects the first two columns of data instead of all 48 columns. Does anyone see any mistake we may have made? Any response would be greatly appreciated! There will always be 48 columns however there number of rows will vary from week to week.

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long

lastRow = 1
lastCol = 1

    While Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastRow, lastCol).Value <> ""
        lastCol = lastCol + 1
    Wend

lastCol = lastCol - 1

    While Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastRow, 1).Value <> ""
        lastRow = lastRow + 1
    Wend

lastRow = lastRow - 1

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Sheet1!R1C1:R" & lastRow & "C" & lastCol, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:= _
    xlPivotTableVersion12

ActiveSheet.PivotTableWizard TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the last columns of data try replacing

```
While Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastRow, lastCol).Value <> ""
    lastCol = lastCol + 1
Wend
```

for

```
lastCol = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

This will get you the last column on the right that has data in row 1.

and

```
While Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastRow, 1).Value <> ""
    lastRow = lastRow + 1
Wend
```

for

```
lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
```

This will get you the last row of data that has data in column 1

---

If you have blank cells then this could be interfering with you setting your range. Looping to get the end values also seems very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a blank in C1, so the loop is stopping.  Try this

```
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = 48
```